# In Android on screen rotation activity is getting recreated, even if the rotation is prevented in the manifest on Oneplus6t(android 9)?

Tags: android, orientation, screen-rotation

In Android on screen, rotation activity is getting recreated, even if the rotation is prevented in the manifest. It is only on Oneplus6t(android 9) in lower OS versions it is working fine?

```
<activity
        android:name="com.oracle.aconex.drawing.DrawingActivity"
        android:configChanges="orientation"
        android:exported="false"
        android:screenOrientation="fullUser"/>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't know the exact reason but when I added **screenSize** in the configchanges it started working in the device.

```
<activity
        android:name=".drawing.DrawingActivity"
        android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"
        android:exported="false"
        android:screenOrientation="fullUser"
       />
```

Answer (score 0):

From Android Developers website,

> "fullUser"    If the user has locked sensor-based rotation, this behaves
>   the same as user, otherwise it behaves the same as fullSensor and
>   allows any of the 4 possible screen orientations. Added in API level
>   18.

From my understanding, as long as a user doesn't lock the auto-rotate feature, the device and apps can still respond to auto-rotation. I recommend using `portrait` or `landscape` to fully prevent your app from auto-rotation. If you need some freedom on rotation, use `sensorPortraint` or `sensorLandscape`.

Comment: maybe it's behavior changed. if something works on a newer api level, it doesn't mean it works on older devices. Tbh, I haven't seen anyone use `fulluser` for the `screenOrientation`